# Aggregate on inner object array

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to write a query by performing an aggregate on one of its properties that is an array of objects. As an example in the below json structure I want the country and the biggest airport as two columns in the output

```
[
  {
    "Country": "US",
    "Airports": [
      {
        "Name": "Kodiak Airport",
        "Area": "100"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Homer Airport",
        "Area": "87"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Country": "Mexico",
    "Airports": [
      {
        "Name": "Gulfport-Biloxi International Airport",
        "Area": "94"
      },
      {
        "Name": "El Paso International Airport",
        "Area": "68"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so the reuslt will be 2 columns, country name and biggest airport's name as below:
Country    Airport

---

US          Kodiak Airport
Mexico   Gulfport-Biloxi International Airport.

The following query returns country and the first airport's name in the array airports_s.

```
MyLogs_CL
| project country_s, Airports = todynamic(airports_s)
| project country_s, Airports[0].name
```

But I don't how to perform an aggregate on that array and return the object which has the highest area among them.

Comment: Can you confirm you're using c# and .net?

Comment: @Mehdi Ibrahim No, I want the output in log analytics